# Why does "return next()" cause "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]"

Tags: api, express, post, dialogflow-es

I created a Dialogflow chatbot to convert currencies. I am writing my own Dialogflow fulfillment that calls an API to do the conversation as the user requests. I keep on getting the "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]" error with  "return next()" in my code. Once it's commented out, my code works fine.

I keep on getting the "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]" error with  "return next()" in my code. Once it's commented out, my code works fine. I'd like to understand why.enter code here

```js
"use strict";

const express        = require("express"),
      request        = require("request"),
      app            = express()

app.use(express.json())

// POST route handler
app.post("/", (req, res, next) => {
  let { queryResult } = req.body;
  if (queryResult) {
    const { outputCurrency, amountToConvert } = queryResult.parameters;
    // Check if input currency code === output currency code
    if (amountToConvert.currency === outputCurrency) {
      const { amount } = amountToConvert;
      let responseText = `Well, ${amount} ${outputCurrency} is obviously equal to ${amount} ${outputCurrency}!`;
      let respObj = {
        fulfillmentText: responseText
      };
      res.json(respObj); //send back object to Dialogflow
    } else {
      // Query the currencyconverter API to fetch rates and create a response
      convertCurrency(amountToConvert, outputCurrency, (error, result) => {
        if (!error && result) {
          let respObj = {
            fulfillmentText: result  //send back response to Dialogflow
          };
          res.json(respObj);          
        }
      });
    }
  }
  //return next();   //with this line running, I keep getting 
                    //Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
});

//function to call API and convert currency
const convertCurrency = (amountToConvert, outputCurrency, cb) => {
    const { amount, currency } = amountToConvert;
    const reqObj = //assemble the api request
    { 
      url: "https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert",
      qs: {        
        q: `${currency}_${outputCurrency}`,
        compact: "ultra",
        apiKey: "f0a68e5b725035985796"
      },
      method: "GET",
      json: true
    }
    return request( 
      reqObj,
      (error, response, body) => {   
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
          let computedValue = Math.round(
            body[`${currency}_${outputCurrency}`] * amount
          );
          cb( //this is the message i send back to Dialogflow (DF)
            null,
            `${amount} ${currency} converts to about ${outputCurrency} ${computedValue} as per current rates!`
          );
        } else {
          cb(error, null);
        }
      }
    );
  };

app.listen(3000, () =>{
  console.log("server started")
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In code paths where you send a response, you do not want to also call `next()`.  Your code is doing that and that leads to some other route down the line also trying to send a response which leads to the "headers have already been sent" message internal to Express.

Calling `next()` will continue routing to other routes and once you've sent a response, you don't want to do that.  Your code needs to send one and only one response for every possible path through the route handler.   Further since this route handler is "handling" the route, there is no reason to call `next()` on any path through the code.  Instead all possible paths through the code must either send a successful response or an error response and one and only one response.

Here's one attempt to cleanup all possible paths through the code and add appropriate error responses:

```
// POST route handler
app.post("/", (req, res, next) => {
  let { queryResult } = req.body;
  if (!queryResult) {
    res.status(400).json({error: "Missing data in post"})
  } else {
    const { outputCurrency, amountToConvert } = queryResult.parameters;
    // Check if input currency code === output currency code
    if (amountToConvert.currency === outputCurrency) {
      const { amount } = amountToConvert;
      let responseText = `Well, ${amount} ${outputCurrency} is obviously equal to ${amount} ${outputCurrency}!`;
      res.json({fulfillmentText: responseText}); //send back object to Dialogflow
    } else {
      // Query the currencyconverter API to fetch rates and create a response
      convertCurrency(amountToConvert, outputCurrency, (error, result) => {
        if (error || !result) {
          console.log(error);
          res.status(500).json({error: "currency conversion failure"});
        } else  {
          res.json({fulfillmentText: result});   //send back response to Dialogflow
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation

Comment: @KelvinChen - If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.